# Assertion error with jit from numba and hypergeom from scipy

Tags: python, scipy, numba

I'm trying to use this function :

```
@jit
def pv (matrix1, matrix2, vec, n):
    for i in range (n):
        for j in range (n):
            matrix1[i,j] = 1 - sum (hypergeom.pmf(X, n, int(vec[i]), int(vec[j])) for X in range(matrix2[i,j]))
```

but I got *Assertion error*, a lot of thing I don't even start to understand (traceback from numba) and at the end *AssertionError: Failed in object mode pipeline (step: object mode frontend)*. I suspect is something related to hyergeom but I don't see where I did wrong

Edit: in the end I did not find a way to implement a code working with @jit, but I find the function scipy.stats.hypergeom.cdf that does this:

```
sum (hypergeom.pmf(X, n, int(vec[i]), int(vec[j])) for X in range(matrix2[i,j]))
```

```
from scipy.stats import hypergeom

hypergeom.cdf(m2[i,j], n, v[i], v[j])
```

Although this solution sped up the code, the for loops are still really slow (with n =5053 takes more than half an hour to run)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great idea to use Numba for this type of thing but unfortunately, as you suspect, it doesn't support the `hypergeom` function.  You didn't do anything wrong here -- it's just not supported so I think you won't be able to use Numba in this case.

A list of what is supported is at https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html

An approach I have taken in the past when something like this happens is to try to write my own version of the unsupported function using the subset of numpy that numba **does** support but success rate is variable and it can cause a whole new array of problems (Swapping out a debugged, tested library function for your own implementation of something can result in dumpster fires).  Without looking at the source of `hypergeom.pmf`, I have no idea if this would be viable route here.

Comment: I've tried to write a code and I failed miserably, but I found that the sum is another function is given by the function hypergeom.cdf. The source code if you want to take a look is at [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html].